# if statement in a bookmarklet not working

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I made a bookmarklet for people in my school. Here is the code: `document.body.contentEditable=true;` there is also another bookmarklet to turn it off: `document.body.contentEditable=false;` These worked, but I wanted to try to make them into one bookmarklet. I tried this and failed. Here is the code: `if (document.body.contentEditable == true) { document.contentEditable = false; } else { document.body.contentEditable = true; }` I have no clue why it does not work. Someone please help.

Comment: `document.contentEditable` or `document.body.contentEditable`? Do you know what [`document.body.contentEditable`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) is? It’s never `true`. Consider using [`isContentEditable`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/isContentEditable) instead.

Comment: document.body.contentEditable is document.contentEditable ever true? thank you

Comment: The new code still does not work : `if (document.body.isContentEditable == true) { document.contentEditable = false; } else { document.body.contentEditable = true; }`

Comment: Again, pay attention to where you’ve written `document.contentEditable` and where you’ve written `document.body.contentEditable` and realize that one of them does not exist.

Comment: still not working. I fixed where i used document.body and document: `if (document.body.isContentEditable == true) { document.body.contentEditable = false; }; if (document.body.isContentEditable == false) { document.body.contentEditable = true; };`

Comment: You need to replace `; if (document.body.isContentEditable == false)` by `else`, or else you will just override whatever the first `if` statement did immediately.

Comment: still doesn't work: `if (document.body.isContentEditable == true) { document.body.contentEditable = false; } else {document.body.isContentEditable = true}`

Comment: Read the documentation again. `isContentEditable` is read-only. You _read_ `isContentEditable`, and you _set_ `contentEditable`.

Comment: why are you leaving ".body" out sometimes??

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way to do it:

```js
javascript: (function () {
  const body = document.body;
  body.contentEditable = !body.isContentEditable;
})();
```